# What is the equivalent to Kusto's CountOf() function in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: substring, azure-data-factory, filenames

My requirement is to extract a string from filenames using a ADF variable, I need to extract the string until the final underscore '_' and the number of underscores vary in every filename as seen in the below example.

```html
abc_xyz_20221221.txt         --> abc_xyz
abc_xyz_a1_20221221.txt      --> abc_xyz_a1
abc_c_ab_a1_20221221.txt     --> abc_c_ab_a1
abc_c_ab_a1_a11_20221221.txt --> abc_c_ab_a1_a11
```

I tried to get it done using indexof() to get the position of the final underscore but it does not accept negative values, so I got the below logic which works in KQL (Azure Data Explorer) but fails in ADF because there is no CountOf() in this tool. Is there any equivalent function in ADF or can you please suggest me how to achieve the same in ADF?

```
substring("abc_xyz_20221221.txt", 0, 
                      indexof("abc_xyz_20221221.txt", "_", 0, 
                              strlen("abc_xyz_20221221.txt"), 
                                     countof("abc_xyz_20221221.txt", '_')))
```

Comment: There is a lastIndexOf function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#lastindexof

Comment: wow, never used LastIndexOf and it did the job for me. Thanks Joel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also using split and join inside ForEach activity.

**Array for ForEach activity:**

```
["abc_xyz_20221221.txt","abc_xyz_a1_20221221.txt","abc_c_ab_a1_20221221.txt","abc_c_ab_a1_a11_20221221.txt"]
```

**Append variable inside ForEach:**

```
@join(take(split(item(), '_'),add(length(split(item(), '_')),-1)),'_')
```

[image]

**Result in an array variable:**

[image]

As mentioned by **@Joel Cochran**, use the below expression in the append variable inside ForEach with `lastIndexOf()`.

```
@substring(item(),0,lastindexof(item(),'_'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a just a simpler form of what @Rakesh called out above . The only difference being , his implementation is iterating . In my case the file name is stored in a variable named foo

```
@substring(variables('foo'),0,lastindexof(variables('foo'),'_'))
```

output

[image]